# Error in use index to find entry in an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am a new learner in python and met the following error.
I want to find a particular index in an array; so I did

```
a=np.array([10,11,12,13,14])
a.index(3)
```

It shows 'np.adarray' object has no attribute 'index'

How to fix it?  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `[...]`:

```
a=np.array([10,11,12,13,14])
print(a[3])
```

Result:

```
13
```